# Android GridView get child item don't work

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to get GridView child item, I use code below, but it doesn't work.

```
    mAppGridAdapter = new gridadapter(mContext, appPackageInfos);
    mAppManaGridView.setAdapter(mAppGridAdapter);

    if(mAppManaGridView.getCount()>0)
    {                                                                       
        mAppManaGridView.setSelection(0);
        Log.d("adan", "adan>" + mAppManaGridView.getCount());
        Log.d("adan", mAppManaGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()  +  ",  "  +mAppManaGridView.getLastVisiblePosition());
        for(int visiblePosition = mAppManaGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition <= mAppManaGridView.getLastVisiblePosition(); visiblePosition++) {
            View item = mAppManaGridView.getChildAt(visiblePosition);
            // make something
            Log.d("adan", "adan>" + item.getWidth()+","  +item.getHeight() );

        }

    }
```

the debug log message shown, that it can get the child count, but it can't get any child item of the GridView:

```
D/adan    (11457): adan>165
D/adan    (11457): 0,  -1
```

I also tried this code, but the return item is null, it crashed with nullPointerException.

```
    if(mAppManaGridView.getCount()>0)
    {                                                                       
        mAppManaGridView.setSelection(0);
        Log.d("adan", "adan>" + mAppManaGridView.getCount());
        View item = mAppManaGridView.getChildAt(0);
        // make something
        Log.d("adan", "adan>" + item.getWidth()+","  +item.getHeight() );
    }
```

can you help me to solve this problem? It troubled me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

getChildAt() returns the child view of a your GridView. Children views positions and your data positions are not the same, because AdapterViews recycle and reuse child views. That way, you can have 100 items of your data in adapter and only 7 child views in gridview.

This is fundamental and you should watch google IO video about listview (the stuff they describe there is mostly for all AdapterViews)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: if the item is dynamically generated, so how to get the item size of the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting getChildCount() as 0 and getChildItem(i) as null in all fragment callback methods. But when I am setting a listener on grid view(i.e onSetItemClickListener()), I am getting the child item or getChildrenCount as non-null.

If you want a child item/items to be default, then write code in the grid view adapter(implement Base Adapter) when getting the view (from getView()). You can use Viewmodel or Interfaces for communications(passing data).